# while loop javascript logic

Tags: javascript, loops

Can anybody explain this while loop for me? It part of the roman numeral challenge on free code camp - it's not mine, I did my own but it was much more code. I'm trying understand this one to improve my own. Anyway, the while loop is totally throwing me. Any help would be awesome.

```
function romans(num){
    var roman = "";
    var romanNumerals = ["M","CM","D","CD","C","XC","L","XL","X","IX","V","IV","I"];
    var numbers = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];

    for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        //If the num was 5 then then it would read 5 greater than 1000?
        while (num >= numbers[i]) {
            roman = roman + romanNumerals[i]
            //5 minus 1000? 
            num = num - numbers[i]
        }
    }

    return roman;
}

console.log(romans(5))
```

Comment: `//5 minus 1000?` Only if math is completely broken and `5 >= 1000` would be true :) For `num === 5` the `while` loop will only be executed once for `i === 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` starts as the desired input, then you find the numbers that add up to `num`, starting at the biggest roman numeral (`numbers[0]`).

You repeat with the while loop because you might need multiple copies of the letter (i.e. `"III" == 3`)

`romans(5)` will not trigger the while loop until `numbers[10]` (because as you say `5 >= 1000 == false`,) at this point you append the character V to `roman`, and subtract 5 from `num`. The while loop will never again trigger since `num` is now 0.

Try thinking through it with `romans(3001)` and you will see the while loop trigger 3 times for M/1000, then get skipped 10 times, then trigger once for I/1

Comment: Dangit im to slow :'(

Answer (score 1):

```js
function romans(num){
var roman = "";
var romanNumerals=["M","CM","D","CD","C","XC","L","XL","X",
"IX","V","IV","I"];
var numbers = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];

for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){

    //If the num was 5 then then it would read 5 greater than 1000?
    console.log("comparing: " + numbers[i]);
    console.log(" with: " + num);
    while(num >= numbers[i]){
    console.log("entered");
        roman = roman + romanNumerals[i]
        //5 minus 1000? 
        num = num - numbers[i]
        console.log('subtracting: ' + numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return roman
}
console.log(romans(44))
```

It will go down the line of numbers until it finds one that is smaller: for example 44:

In the for it'll go through the numbers array until it finds a number then 44 (during the iterations before the while loop is never entered).

When it finds a number smaller then 44 it enters the while loop and takes the romanNumerals at the position of i in that iteration, in this case 40. Then it lowers the original number by 40 (44-40=4) and then exits the loop going back into the for to search for a number lower then 4.